# Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDK - Switching app user

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I'm currently building a clienteling app that integrated the Mobile Push SDK on both iOS and Android and encountered some issue on switching the account.

I found that when I login to user A, and set contact key to A, the Inbox Messages will be send to this device.
However, I logout user A and switch to a user B, I should set the contact key to B. But seems the inbox messages are associated with the Device instead of Contact, I can still see the inbox messages that were sent to contact A previously.

My question is, how should we deal with this situation, to prevent from seeing the previous inbox messages if the contact key has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

First, as of 2018-11-16 neither the SDK nor the Marketing Cloud supports the use-case you describe.  Please open a Voice of Customer (VoC) request through your account manager.  The more of these requests that exist the more likely it is the feature will be implemented.

Now, we do have people who have successfully implemented your use-case.  It requires that you send the `ContactKey` (or similar unique identifier) along with your inbox message in a "Custom Key".  Then you would implement your inbox message adapter such that you inspect your custom key to determine whether or not your message should be included in the message list.

**UPDATE 20190108** -- Apparently, I have misspoken.  This was our understood solution from the SDK's perspective until such time that the messages could be filtered at the system level for a given contact, but we are mistaken.  You are correct in your comment that messages are rendered at the time that they are downloaded.  There is work underway to allow for the use-case you describe.

**UPDATE 20200924** -- Inbox messages can now be targeted to a Contact rather than a device.  Your application in the Marketing Cloud must be configured to do so.  Please contact your support representative for more information.

Comment: Hi Bill, we tried this before as well. But soon we realised it won't solve the issue. As the inbox messages are re-rendered (not cached) at time of request from the SDK, the custom key is not fixed and will be updated every time the contact key has been switched.

Comment: It's a basic feature that SDKs should be able to offer to developers. Firebase and crashlytics for example do that. This is not a solution for the current problem.

I'm facing the same issue with notifications. As we have a way to set the current contact key, we should be able to clear it.

Comment: Poster did not ask for a way to clear `Contact Key` @douglas.iacovelli

Comment: I'm sorry about that. The use case seemed pretty close to me. I'm opening a new question for that matter

Comment: No big deal @douglas.iacovelli and it brought attention to this question/answer which deserved an update :). Thanks!

Comment: @BillMote Hi thanks for providing this update. May I know what's the official name of the feature you mentioned? I think bind messages with the user make more sense than binding messages with device.. Did the SFMC release notes mentioned this? And what we should ask for when talk to the support representative?

Comment: I don't know if there's an official name for the feature, but ask them to enable "per-contact messaging for Inbox messages on your MID."

Comment: Hi @BillMote the team has asked the Marketing Cloud support and we got a reply saying: I have checked internally and we are not aware of this enablement options..... May I know if you have any idea?

Comment: Support is wrong.  Have them at-mention me.