# Inbox Messages not updating when switching Account

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, inbox

I am developing a client App using marketingcloudsdk-6.3.4 for implementing Inbox Messages on both iOS and Android. I am facing some issue on switching the account

Steps:

Login as user A

Set unique contact key for A

Send messages to that contact key

Check for Inbox Messages

Logout user A and switch to user B

Set a unique contact key for B

Again Check Inbox Messages

Here for both user getting the same Inbox Messages.

My question is, how should we deal with this situation, to prevent from seeing the previous inbox messages if the contact key has been changed?

Comment: Duplicate of [Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDK - Switching app user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239554/marketing-cloud-mobile-push-sdk-switching-app-user)

Comment: If the answers from the duplicate don't fully address your question, please edit your question to explain why this is so.  If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the duplicate question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite or "follow" it and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: I don't  have sufficient reputation to add comment,i need its updated answer. [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/239554/87655) the  answer  is not complted.So i posted it again as new question.

Comment: The best course of action is to upvote the duplicate question and star or follow it. When you upvote it, it gets bumped up on the question feed for everyone else to see that there's a renewed interest in it. It's easy to quickly [acquire additional reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) by (for example) editing questions.

Comment: Thanks for the info @identigral

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a support case through your support representative.  You *can* target inbox messages to a contact, but it must be enabled in your account.

Comment: Thanks @Bill..i have a doubt On what basis SDK downloading the inbox messages to a device?

Comment: You need to open a support case through your support representative. You can target inbox messages to a contact, but it must be enabled in your account.